# Select rows with same Name and their posible ID (could be Null)

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have this

For every username there is at most one unique associated not null `col2` value and potentially some null `col2` values.

```
+----------+-------+
| username | col2  |
+----------+-------+
| a        | 1r1   |
| a        | 1r1   |
| b        | 1z2   |
| b        | null  |
| c        | 1t3   |
| c        | null  |
| c        | 1t3   |
| d        | null  |
+----------+-------+
```

And I'm looking for an output like this:

```
+----------+------+
| username | col2 |
+----------+------+
| a        | 1r1  |
| b        | 1z2  |
| c        | 1t3  |
| d        | null |
+----------+------+
```

The first colums are names of companies and the second are the ID but sometimes (user error input) there is a few companies that doesnt have ID, and i want all the companies names with their posible ID's

I believe it could be with `coalesce` but I'm stuck...

Thanks for the help

Comment: What if there are 2 rows with same `username` but different `col2` values? Say, `d 120` and `d 121`?

Comment: thank god the db i have thats not the case @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and either `MIN()` or `MAX()` to get rid of the nulls and show one row per username:

```
SELECT username, MIN(col2) AS col2
FROM tableX
GROUP BY username ;
```

or remove them in advance and use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, col2
FROM tableX
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL ;
```

The two queries above will show same results, unless there are usernames with only nulls or with different (non-null) `col2` values.

Comment: i forgot to put it on the question, but i also have values that have only nulls in the col2.
The first colums are names of companies and the second are the ID but sometimes (user error input) there is a few companies that doesnt have ID, and i want all the companies names with their posible ID's

Comment: If you want those to appear in the result (with `'username' - NULL`) then use query 1. If you don't want them to appear at all use query 2.